# Contact Form 7 printing in screen code instead show the form?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am working with a site, Wordpress version 3.9.1 and contact form 7 , version 3.9 (stable for this wp version)

When I set the contact form code into a page, like this

```
[contact-form-7 id="14414" title="Contact form 1"]
```

And when I go to my screen, I see that exact code as a text output, instead the actual form (the plugin is active)

The code is not between a P tag or something.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities I can think of:

1) You've written in the wrong id

2) You've added the shortcode to Visual view instead of the Text (HTML) view in the editor

If that doesn't solve your problem, see if you can get the contact form to output another way:

Try adding `do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="14414" title="Contact form 1"]' );` to your `template.php` file and see if it displays.

If that doesn't work try `echo do_shortcode(apply_filters("the_content", "[contact-form-7 id='14414' title="Contact form 1]"));` in your `template.php` file.

Comment: Hi, no, it is the correct ID and I am adding as HTML

Answer (score 1):

form-7 id="14414" title="Contact form 1"] in **text** area section.
If its not working please add this in your **page-templates** 
like this.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="14414" title="Contact form 1"]');?>
```